# Is it possible to cross-fade when switching tabs using jQueryUI Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

So I know it is possible to do this fade-in/fade-out effect with jQuery UI Tabs. And this is the code I have to do it:

```
$("#Tabs").tabs({ fx: [{ opacity:'hide', duration:1000 },
                       { opacity:'show', duration:1000 }] });
```

This will fade out current tab completely and only then start fading in the new one, so you end up with this blank space for a split second.

What I actually need is more of a cross-fade effect, meaning that when I click on another tab, the fading in of a new tab would start at the same time as fading out of the current one.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch. Just spent the last thirty minutes trying to get UI Tabs and [Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) to play nicely, without much luck. What I ended up with is [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FEMvP/2/).

You will be disappointed that there are no tabs, but it should be fairly easy to cheat and make those links look like tabs (I'm still trying, I would like this myself).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, looks like it is not possible since this ticket hasn't been completed:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3927